# Reset Administrator password on Ricoh/IBM InfoPrint 1532

Tags: printer, administrator, password-recovery

Not sure if hardware questions are allowed here but not sure where else to go.

My office has at least 100 of these old IBM IP 1532's and a couple dozen 1832's. There was an administrator password set on them years ago to prevent end user modifications. We've since needed to get back into them but none of the passwords that management has provided are working.

They've authorized me to go back into them and reset the passwords if I can figure out how. I know there is a jumper terminal on the system board which I did try to short and reset the machine but the password stayed in place.

Anyone know if I'm on the right track?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting the printer to factory defaults as follows:

```
1 Make sure the printer is on and Ready appears on the display.
2 Press the "key" button on the operator panel.
3 Press "down" until the "tick" appears next to "Settings", and then press "tick"
4 Press "down" until the "tick" appears next to "Setup", and then press "tick"
5 Press "down" until the "tick" appears next to "Factory Defaults", and then press "tick"
6 Press "down" until the "tick" appears next to "Restore Now, and then press "tick"
```

The message Restoring Factory Defaults appears, followed by the Ready message

This is from the [User Manual pg 96](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/281830/Ricoh-Infoprint-1532.html?page=95#manual). However, I suspect it will ask for the Administrator password before you can get in there. In that case, my only advice is to contact Ricoh service.